# Implementing cache with multiple consumer and single producer in java

Tags: java, caching, producer

My requirement is to maintain a fixed size cache which provides support for multiple consumer and single producer in a java based web application. My data is like this:

Key 1,Key 2,Values

123,abc,List1

123,def,List2

234,xyz,List3

clients or consumers will query this cache based on key1 and key2.
So if multiple consumers try to access the cache at the same time for same key1 & 2, they all should get the same data from cache in response.

I am looking for the best possible data structure to use.
Also note that cache size is fixed hence if producer before trying to insert record should remove the first element if cache is full.

I currently use a map within a map. i.e. key 1 is for the outer map and key 2 is for the inner map. However I need to look through it to get the information which i feel is inefficient.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, i would flatten your cache to a single, 2 component key (i.e. combine key1 and key2 into a composite key class).

secondly, i would use an existing cache implementation instead of re-inventing the wheel.  for "simple" usage, you could synchronize access to a LinkedHashMap (which you can limit by size using the `removeEldestEntry()` method).  if you need more sophisticated thread handling, then i'd look at something like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) or [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) (mentioned in other answer).

Comment: thanks for the response to all of you...I looked at Guava but the eviction process did not suit us. Coz we need eviction based on size but not everything but just the oldest record. Also I should have clarified on my second key. The way I need values is for key 2 > input key. User will provide input key 1 and input key 2. But values returned should be equal  to input key 1 and greater than input key 2.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained), a useful utility library by Google, that includes some great caching functionality. In particular, it supports a maximum size, and will handle evictions automatically.

As for the 2 keys problem, why not wrap the Guava cache (or whatever implementation) with another class that takes the 2 keys and generates a single key from the combination, eg:

```
public class MyCache<Key, Value> {
    private final Cache<CacheKey, Value> guavaCache = CacheBuilder.build()

    public void put(Key keyOne, Key keyTwo, Value value) {
        cache.put(new CacheKey(keyOne, keyTwo), value);
    }

    public Value get(Key keyOne, Key keyTwo) {
        return cache.getIfPresent(new CacheKey(keyOne, keyTwo));
    }

    private static final class CacheKey {
        private final Key keyOne;
        private final Key keyTwo;

        CacheKey(Key keyOne, Key keyTwo) {
             this.keyOne = keyOne;
             this.keyTwo = keyTwo;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = keyOne == null ? 0 : keyOne.hashCode();
            return hash + 31 * keyTwo == null ? 0 : keyTwo.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            // implementation omitted
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have custom `Map` implementation backed up with desired size `ConcurrentHashMap` with load factor 1 and have a counter inside to make sure your wrapped `ConcurrentHashMap` does not contain more than you want it to contain.

Answer (score 0):

you could maintain two ConcurrentHashMaps for the two keys, or one if there is no chance of a conflict. To remember the oldest keys you can maintain a queue with the two oldest keys to remove when cache size limit is reached.